# VBA Button Insert Letter into selected cell range and paste it into the same cell range on different Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, button, copy, paste

in Sheet1 I have a button which puts the letter "U" into my seleceted range of cells. (Code: Intersect(Selection, Selection) = "U").
Sheet2 hat the same structure (looks identical) as Sheet1, so after I press the button and my selected cells fill up with "U" letters, I want the "U" letter in the selected range of Sheet1 to be copied to the same  cell range in Sheet2. (see IMG1)

[image: IMG1]

Thnak you in advance!

I tired to make a button for Sheet1 and adapat to Sheet2, but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With Selection
    .Value = "U"
    Thisworkbook.worksheets("Sheet2").range(.Address) = "U" 'same range on Sheet2
End With
```

should do what you want